# How to split string by '+' Except inside square brackets

Tags: java

My example string: `a+[b*a+c]+c+[ab+c]` and split by '+'

After split:

```
a
[b*a+c]
c
[ab+c]
```

I can do it for parentheses by using `\\+(?![^()]*\\))` as regex into `input.split(regex)`. But cant figure out for square brackets. I appreciate for any kind of help

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this unless two conditions hold: 1) You are guaranteed to always have matching brackets; and 2) You never have brackets nested, as in `a+[b*[c+d]]`.  See https://xkcd.com/1171/ and http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247 - To avoid the issue, learn what regexes are for and especially when they're NOT the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative lookahead is needed to match a `+` except those put before the closing bracket `\]`

```java
String str = "a+[b*a+c]+c+[ab+c]";
String[] arr = str.split("\\+(?![^\\[]*\\])");

Arrays.stream(arr)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
a
[b*a+c]
c
[ab+c]
```